# redirect the htaccess with 2 parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url with 2 parameters that I want to redirect the user to a clean url

```
https://www.example.com/songs?date=1999&btn-login=
```

I need it to be

```
  https://www.example.com/songs/1999
```

how can I do this?

I have tried this but the url remain as it is without any changes

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /songs\.php\?date=(.*)&btn-login=\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /songs.php?date=$1 [L]
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Are you typing the filename without extension eg **songs** instead of **songs.php** ?

Comment: yes because the /songs is the actual path

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(|.+&)date=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^songs$ /songs/%2? [R=301,L]
```

`%2` is used to read from the 2nd group which should be the full value of the date param in the query string. `?` is used so the query string isn't appended in the redirect. I also made it so that the regex won't allow something like `anotherdate=`.

You can view the regex in detail [here](https://regexper.com/#%5E(%7C.%2B%26)date%3D(%5B%5E%26%5D%2B)).